# Let $K/F$ be a Galois entension, and $Gal(K/F)=S_n$. Prove K is a split field of n degree irreducible polynomial over F.

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, group-actions, symmetry

Here are some of my thoughts.

- Use group theory to show contradiction.

Suppose K is a split field of an irreducible polynomial $f$, $deg f=m>n$. Then $S_n$ isomorphic to a transitive subgroup of $S_m$.
It's sufficient to show that $S_n$ cannot embed into $S_m$ as a transitive subgroup. However, I can't get it.

- Use primitive element theorem to construct a $n$ degree irreducible polynomial.

$S_{n-1}\subseteq S_n=Gal(K/F)$
Let $\alpha$ be the primitive element(i.e. $K=F(\alpha)$), let
$$\beta =\sum_{\sigma \in S_{n-1}}\sigma \alpha$$
Let $O$ be the orbit of $\beta$ under $Gal(K/F)$.$$f(X)=\Pi_{u\in O}(X-u)$$
Then $f(X)$ is $Gal(K/F)$-invariant hence $f(X)\in F[X]$

It's sufficient to show $|O|=n$, but I'm stuck in this last step.

Comment: But $S_4$ is embedded in $S_6$ as a transitive subgroup: look at the action of $S_4$ on subsets of size $2$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Maybe my first idea is wrong. You can look at another idea, is it work?

Comment: @inversion See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296917/field-extension-with-galois-group-s-n-is-the-splitting-field-of-a-polynomial-o?rq=1).